# Cursor moves after end quote and adds double quotes after a single quote in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-cursor

Whenever I type double quotes, the cursor moves outside to the right of the end quote. It is extremely annoying. I mean when I ever type double quotes, the cursor moves to the right i.e, after the end quote which is counter-intuitive because I have to move the cursor to the left and inside the double quotes to right something inside the quotes.

I cannot find an appropriate setting to control this behaviour either. Is there a setting to control the cursor behaviour when typing quotes?

And I have to press `double ""` to add quotes. Is there a setting to change it to a single press to add characters?

Comment: some language keyboards treat the (double) quote key special to add character decoration like `ë`, or you can use the key binding debugging to see which commands are executed when you press a key combo, what do you mean with `right of the end quote` specify exactly what you type on an empty line, **edit your question**

Comment: @rioV8 I mean when I ever type double quotes, the cursor moves to the right i.e, after the end quote which is counter-intuitive because I have to move the cursor to the left and inside the double quotes to right something inside the quotes.

Comment: And I just edit my question as well.

Comment: On the keyboard you have `'` (quote) and `"` (double quote). Your question mixes these, be precise what you mean

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a quote or a double quote. BTW I fixed this. I am posting my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue by following these instructions.

Go to your settings and then type in the filter:

`Auto Closing Overtype`

It's probably either on: **auto** or **always**. Change this to **never**. It should work now (it did for me).

Comment: In my case, I had to change it to `always` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯